# Can choice function in SHA algorithm be used in a simplied way?

Tags: algorithms

While going through the official documentation SHA algorithms from NIST [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf).

There is a choice and Majority function used.
Maj(,,)=(∧)⊕(∧)⊕(∧)
Ch(,,)=(∧)⊕(¬∧)

Can I use Ch (or Maj) function in a simplified version?

eg:

(x^y)⊕(¬∧)
=(x^y)^ ¬(¬∧) + ¬(x^y)^ (¬∧)
=(x^y)^(x + ¬z) + (¬x + ¬y)^ (¬∧)
can be further simplified as

(x^y) + (¬x ^z)

can above simplified version be used ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the details of SHA but
if we interpret $0$ as false and $1$ as true, then $a+b$ and $a \oplus b$ only differ when $a=b=1$.

In your specific case $(x \wedge y)$ and $(\neg x \wedge z)$ cannot both be true.
This is easy to see since you would need to simultaneously have $x=1$ and $x=0$.

It follows that  $(x \wedge y) \oplus (\neg x \wedge z)$  and $(x \wedge y) + (\neg x \wedge z)$ are equivalent. The same holds true if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are binary numbers and $\neg$, $\wedge$, and $\oplus$ are interpreted as bitwise operators.

This equality does **not** hold for the case of $\text{Maj}(x,y,z)$, as you can check by setting $x=y=z=1$.

Comment: that's really insightful... I guess I should've added those boundary conditions earlier . Putting x as both 0 and 1 would yield either (0 xor z) or ( y xor 0) respectively which is just another way of saying it's a choice between y and z bit value since one of the other operand is always 0 , the xor can be replaced here with bitwise OR. Hence the name choice function. Having said that , could there be a reason of choosing XOR over OR here? I mean is XOR more efficient than OR in low level implementation? Thanks a lot btw for this answer. Really appreciate

Comment: Sorry, I don't know whether the OR function is more efficient that a XOR on at a low level. I would guess that it depends on the architecture.

Comment: Thats true, I guess this was chosen based on CPU arch. and programming language they were using. I tried searching for the comparison. [link] https://lemire.me/blog/2010/03/12/which-is-fastest-integer-addition-or-xor/     " compile with gcc, xor is 10-20% faster. When I compile the same code with g++, add is about 10% faster.". Thanks anyway.